# Do I need the article "the" in this example

Tags: articles

I am going to buy this record of the clash "london calling" through mailorder but as I have already a previous order of the same mailorder on hold, I'd like both orders to be sent together to save **on postage or on the postage**

I would say on postage sounds better but it is not postage in general it is postage for these 2 orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would include 'the'. However, I would tend to agree with Peter that most native speakers may not. Remember, just because native speakers use a certain structure more often doesn't make it more correct, only more common.

Ex:

(1&2: my own made up examples)

1. Our company pays for postage on all orders. (company policy)
2. The postage on your order has been included as a courtesy. (not a policy)

The postage wasn't paid on it, and that was another thing to worry about.

Tom Sawyer Abroad 
Mark Twain (Samuel Clemens)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example, either using or not using "***the***" will not change the meaning.  Native speaker will more often not use "***the***"

> ...sent together to save on postage.

If you were more specific

> ...sent together to save on **the** $2.50 postage.
>   ...sent together to save on **the** postage *of my order*.